# Realistic rug with blender?

Tags: particles, hair

Can I have some guidance or tutorials how to make phototrealistic rug like this with the particle system?

Here's the kind of result I want to achieve, really realistic, long hair, and a sort of different reaction to light like fresnel when the particle is oriented to différents faces

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

dont hesitate to put the image in full screen , in mini you may think that the level of detail is not important but when you see it at 1500x2000 its totally different

Thanks

Comment: I guess it really depends on the goal, is it for pictures, or video, will it be for close-up shots or will you stay far from the carpet, etc... because you could simply give a texture to your plane with some effects like normals and fresnel and it could work perfectly

Comment: like those image for example , with a simple textureat this distance  it will look totally horrible

Comment: Hi. Please only ask one, specific question at a time.